# Updating native activity from main thread

Tags: android, callback, native

I am using a Bluetooth LE device to read from and write data to.
Reading is fine but when I want to write characteristic with some data from ui, I am having trouble.

I have the data in another class in the native project and from there I want to update gatt characteristic on `mainactivity`
My `bluetoothGattcallback n` handler to update data to ui are both inside `mainactivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback{

public void writeCharacteristicToDevice(byte[] bytes){ 
        //all code is present here
        mConnectedGATT.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
    }
}
```

There is another class (outside of this Activity) that receives data from UI and converts to bytes and here I want to call writeCharacteristicToDevice method

```
public class SensorData{
public static void reqSlave(String data) {
//how to call writeCharacteristic here?
}}
```

I have also implemented a handler inside MainActivity can i use that? but how?

```
public Handler mRxHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        switch(msg.what){

        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a message bus - Otto, GreenRobot, etc.